# How to rewrite subfolder with .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Lets say I have this url:

```
http://www.example.com/page
```

And this code in my .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)\/?$ index.php?pag=$1 [NC,L]
```

It works, but if i go to this url:

```
http://www.example.com/page/another-page
```

It will return 404.

In the code from my .htaccess, i get the $_GET['page'].

Basically, i want to get the url as:

```
index.php?pag=page/another-page
```

And without returning 404.

Comment: Does not works `/page/a` url too?

Comment: Could you adjust the title of your question so it will show up when others search for `rewrite`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually use this pattern:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: If it does not works, check also your mod_rewrite is on... For example: `in_array('mod_rewrite', apache_get_modules());`